Ubuntu and many other Linux distributions have this IPv6 method: “Automatic, DHCP only", what exactly is it doing?
My local network is using stateful IPv6, prefix length is /64. The IPv6 RA from router has both M-bit and O-bit enabled, and the prefix option also has L-bit and A-bit enabled.
When Ubuntu client set IPv6 method to "Automatic", it sets one SLAAC address from IPv6 RA, and also acquires an /128 IPv6 address and DNS from DHCPv6 server. The local network prefix is added to on-link route correctly, and the default route (link-local address of router) is also set correctly. Everything works as expected.
But when Ubuntu client set IPv6 method to "Automatic, DHCP only", it acquires IPv6 address and DNS from DHCPv6 server, and nothing else. The on-link route is not added, and the default route is also empty. As if it ignores IPv6 RA completely. And of course the network is simply useless under this circumstances, as it can reach nothing except the ff02::1 multicast.
Yes I can just set the computer to "Automatic" and use it happily, but I don't understand what's the purpose of "Automatic, DHCP only" if the system is not taking any reference from RA.

It's only assigning an address: https://askubuntu.com/questions/897697/ipv6-unique-local-address-and-dhcpv6

@skitheo the link is completely irrelevant to the question. "Automatic, DHCP only" ignores IPv6 RA and thus both default route and on-link route are not set, and that means Ubuntu client can't even connect to other host using same network prefix on the same local network. This render the whole network scheme completely useless. And I want to know why Ubuntu (and other distributions) have such useless option. P.S.: both macOS and Windows don't have such option like "Automatic, DHCP only".

NetworkManager  ipv6.method=dhcp  is only DHCP, yes.
As router advertisements are not installed in the interface, there is no default gateway. Absent a route being configured with some other means, this connection will not have a way off link.  Which might a feature depending on what the network is supposed to do.
Again assuming only DHCP, would only have a prefix assigned if using prefix delegation. Neighbor discovery would still work, but with what addresses if stateless autoconfig was disabled. I am not aware of anything forbidding a DHCP server from issuing an address in a prefix it delegated.  Just seems weird given the usual operational model of the server not caring what the client does with the prefix.
Some time ago, DHCPv6 only was removed from nm, only to be re-added later. Apparently there are use cases, although I am having difficulty contriving one. Maybe stateless DHCP where its only to provide DNS and other configuration, not addresses.
Most NetworkManager users would instead want ipv6.method=auto.
